# Is it necessary to start a windows 8 app at least once to enable background taks and/or push notifications

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, push

I understand how i can tie my application to the windows push notification service but the code i have to write to do so will only be reached when my app is started by the user. What if i want my application to receive push notifications when it has just been installed ?

the same question applies to background tasks

Comment: Is there a specific reason you think your app will not be started when it's installed?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be very useful.  You have to declare them in your app manifest so Windows knows how to automatically start them.  Declarations tab in the IDE.  Covered pretty well [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up push notification channels and background tasks does require and app to be run at least once. You can, however, set up periodic notifications in Windows 8.1 through an entry in the manifest, so that you can have a live tile experience after install but before the app is run. If you do that, you can at least surface some info on the live tile right away to invite the user into the app, after which you can customize the experience much more with push notifications and background tasks.

You can find the periodic update URI field in the manifest editor's Application tab under Tile Update. The XML schema ref is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn391689.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Who will install the background agent or create push notification channel in this case? Yes, it should.